# PHP Login System Redirect not working

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a login/registration system and the registration part is working fine. However, now I am trying to login and when you login it should start a session and redirect you to account.php page but it's not doing that. It's just refreshing the page and doing nothing else.

Index page:

```
<?php
include 'dbh.php';
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users where id=".$_SESSION['id']);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
}
# REGISTRATION HANDLER
if(isset($_POST['rsubmit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $plainpass = $_POST['password'];
    $password = password_hash($plainpass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $btn = "Account created! Please login";
}else {
    $btn = "Register";
}
# LOGIN HANDLER
if(isset($_POST['lsubmit'])){
    $lemail = $_POST['lemail'];
    $lpassword = $_POST['lpassword'];
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users where email='$lemail'");
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    if(password_verify($lpassword, $row['password'])){
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id']; 
        Header("Location: account.php");
    }
} else {

}
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Liam4Life</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form" action="index.php" method="POST">
      <input required name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
      <input required name="rpassword" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
      <input required name="remail" type="email" placeholder="Email address"/>
      <button>Register</button>
      <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form" action="index.php" method="POST">
      <input required name="lemail" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
      <input required name="lpassword" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
      <button type="submit" name="lsubmit">Login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

DBH.php:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "game");
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());  
}
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
}
?>
```

Comment: check if you have `?>` in dbh.php - if so, remove it. Any whitespace after that will count as output and prevent header-redirection.

Comment: dbh.php will throw an error: `$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];` -> $row is undefined! Or is there something above we don't see?

Comment: also session isn't started in dbh.php yet.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Comment: try to print something after login then exit. maybe you have not successfully login or your username and password is not valid

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Header("Location: account.php"); 
use the following statement

echo "<script>location.href='account.php'</script>";exit;

The issue as mentioned by Jeff, it can be due to space the redirection is not happening. If the above logic works. Then remove additional space in config / else need to add session_start() as the first line of statement in your index.php file and have the header("Location: account.php") logic.

Note:  To debug, ensure the control goes here by printing and adding a exit statement.

Answer (score 0):

try

Index page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbh.php';

-----code---------

?>
```

DBH.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

-----code---------

?>
```

***//session_start(); needed to give top of page and here it is missing in DBH.php. Hence $_SESSION not working***

Answer (score -1):

Try next approach:

```
<?php

session_start();

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "game");
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(!empty($_SESSION['id'])){
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users where id=".(int)$_SESSION['id']);
    if(!$result->num_rows) {
        session_destroy();
        Header("Refresh:0");
        exit;
    }
    Header("Location: account.php");
    exit;
}

# LOGIN HANDLER
if(isset($_POST['lsubmit']) && !empty($_POST['lemail'])){
    $lemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['lemail']);
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users where email='{$lemail}'");
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    if(password_verify($_POST['lpassword'], $row['password'])){
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
        Header("Location: account.php");
        exit;
    }
}
# REGISTRATION HANDLER
elseif(isset($_POST['rsubmit']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
    $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('{$username}', '{$email}', '{$password}')");
    $btn = "Account created! Please login";
}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Liam4Life</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
        <form class="register-form" action="index.php" method="POST">
            <input required name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
            <input required name="rpassword" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
            <input required name="remail" type="email" placeholder="Email address"/>
            <button>Register</button>
            <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
        </form>
        <form class="login-form" action="index.php" method="POST">
            <input required name="lemail" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
            <input required name="lpassword" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
            <button type="submit" name="lsubmit">Login</button>
            <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Manual escaping and things like `(int)` casting are really weak. The only way to do this reliably is with prepared statements, something that actually results in more readable code that is both smaller and harder to get wrong.

Comment: Well, thanks for your vote. I still think that  question was about  login system but not  secure coding. So according to TS's approach (without ORM and using mysqli-functions with row-queries) I  improved the secure using base functions. Besides, I don't think that  `mysqli_real_escape_string` is unreliable. Also `(int)` casting copes well with not-integer variables. I disagree with your appreciation.

Comment: What use is a login system if it's not secure? The only reason you have a login system is because you want security and `mysqli_real_escape_string` comes with no guarantees, you can still make mistakes. Given a single mistake can render everything you've done pointless, prepared statements are the only thing that can reasonably guarantee safety. They're also less code, so I do not know why people insist on using the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function.

Comment: Main purpose of secure in this case is to protect app from hacking database using SQL-injection. We don't check existing user in database or proper input in form. 
What exactly "no quarantees" do you mean?

Comment: If you put `$email` in the query you're *trusting* that you didn't forget to escape it, something that may not be the case. If you put `?` in the query you're not trusting anything, you're leaving it up to the prepared statement system to handle it. In the first case a simple oversight leads to a SQL injection hole. In the second you have a query that won't execute.